# Import point cloud (.ply) into PostgreSQL ( PostGIS )

Tags: postgis, postgresql, import, point-cloud

I am trying to import some point cloud ( .ply file format ) into PostgreSQL Database with PostGIS extension. 
How can I do that? Any Idea? Any Importer?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that right away with the postgis extension. You will need the [pgpointcloud extension](https://github.com/pgpointcloud/pointcloud) next to that and then import with a [PDAL pipeline](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.pgpointcloud.html).

Both tools involve some tweaking with the software and perhaps even building it yourself for pgpointcloud. Please read the documents behind both links carefully.